# ClassNotFound error on JPA and OSGI project

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, osgi, apache-karaf

I have a problem with JPA on OSGI environment.

Some information on environment and framework:

- Runtime environment is karaf 4.1.6.
- org.hibernate.osgi Version 5.2.9.Final.
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api
- org.apache.aries.jpa.container Version   2.6.1

In my project I need two different persistence units on (almost) the same entity classes, cause I need to write in two diffent Oracle schema.

So I have two datasource like this (with different parameters):

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">      


    <bean id="oraDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@******" />
        <property name="username" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/> 
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxTotal" value="20"/>
    </bean>



    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="oraDataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/oraDataSource"/>
        </service-properties>
    </service>
```

This is a semplified persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <persistence-unit name="PU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/oraDataSource)</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- orm class -->
    .....
    <class>my.path.jpa.model.Pratica</class>
    <class>my.path.jpa.model.Tag</class>
    ......
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="false"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>-->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>


  <persistence-unit name="SYM-PU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/symOraDataSource)</non-jta-data-source>
    <!-- orm class -->
    .....
    <class>my.path.jpa.model.Pratica</class>
    <class>my.path.jpa.model.Tag</class>
    ......
    <class>my.path.jpa.model.sym.PraticaSym</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="false"/>
      <!--<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>-->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And this is my felix plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.bundle.plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Meta-Persistence>META-INF/persistence.xml</Meta-Persistence>
        <Export-Package>
          my.path.jpa*
        </Export-Package>
        <Import-Package>           
            org.hibernate.proxy, javassist.util.proxy, oracle.jdbc, *
        </Import-Package>
        <DynamicImport-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver</DynamicImport-Package>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

When I try to install the feature that contains this bundle I have the following error **only the first time** I try to install:

```
2019-10-07T18:50:19,315 | ERROR | CM Configuration Updater (ManagedService Update: pid=[org.apache.aries.jpa.SYM-PU]) | lix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager 1284 | 9 - org.apache.felix.configadmin - 1.8.16 | [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=2531, bundle=8564/mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container/2.6.1]: Unexpected problem updating configuration org.apache.aries.jpa.SYM-PU
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [my.path.jpa.model.Tag]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:104) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885) [8587:org.hibernate.core:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(OsgiPersistenceProvider.java:96) [8589:org.hibernate.osgi:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.ManagedEMF.createAndPublishEMF(ManagedEMF.java:129) [8564:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.ManagedEMF.updated(ManagedEMF.java:125) [8564:org.apache.aries.jpa.container:2.6.1]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updated(ManagedServiceTracker.java:189) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.updateService(ManagedServiceTracker.java:152) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.helper.ManagedServiceTracker.provideConfiguration(ManagedServiceTracker.java:85) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.provide(ConfigurationManager.java:1479) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.ConfigurationManager$ManagedServiceUpdate.run(ConfigurationManager.java:1435) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run0(UpdateThread.java:141) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at org.apache.felix.cm.impl.UpdateThread.run(UpdateThread.java:109) [9:org.apache.felix.configadmin:1.8.16]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : my.path.jpa.model.Tag
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345) ~[?:?]
    ... 16 more
```

If i retry to install the feature everything goes ok!

The problem is always on the second Persistence Unit.
If I try to invert the first with the second PU, declaring SYM-PU first than PU in persistence.xml, the same problem occurs on PU.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: I used karaf inside Talend ESB version 7.1.1, problem solved by updating talend to 7.2.1.

Comment: Karaf version passed from 4.1.6.to 4.2.4